# AWS SDK Builder for javascript reference error

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, builder, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I used the SDK Builder for javascript ([here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/)) by only picking the AWS.firehose service.

When trying to use it from node.js I ran this code :

```
var AWS = require('./aws-sdk-2.6.6.min');
```

And got this error :

> /aws-sdk-2.6.6.min.js:7
>   if(this._events||(this._events={}),"error"===t&&(!this._events.error||s(this._events.error)&&!this._events.error.length)){if(e=arguments[1](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/),e
>   instanceof Error)throw e;var l=new Error('Uncaught, unspecified
>   "error" event. ('+e+")");throw
>   l.context=e,l}if(r=this._events[t],a(r))return!1;if(i(r))switch(arguments.length){case
>   1:r.call(this);break;case 2:r.call(this,arguments[1](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/));break;case
>   3:r.call(this,arguments[1](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/),arguments[2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-building.html));break;default:o=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),r.apply(this,o)}else
>   if(s(r))for(o=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),c=r.slice(),n=c.length,u=0;u
>
> ReferenceError: AWS is not defined
>       at Object. (/aws-sdk-2.6.6.min.js:7:25500)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/index.js:5:11)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)

Is this a bug from AWS SDK builder ?

Am I supposed to include other services ?

Is there more documentation than [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-building.html) ?